# SQl injection getting current user and database priv

Tags: sql, code-injection

I am doing a tutorial a lab on SQL Injection.

I am stuck at retrieving the username of the current user and the priv it has.

I tried Select user FROM dual, select current_user.  In SQLPlus, to get current user I will type

SQL>  show user.

Question being asked:
1.  Use a SQL Injection string in the Search field to get the name of the database user that the application is connecting to the database with.
2.  Use a SQL Injection string in the Search field to get the system privileges granted to the user that the application is connecting to the database with.

Please help.  Thanks

Comment: Questions being asked:

Comment: Are you sure database in your tutorial is actually `Oracle`? Please read about `SQL Injection` and what it actually looks like (syntax).

Comment: What DB are you using, Oracle from the use of `SQLPlus`? Google told me about this page: http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/sql-injection/oracle-sql-injection-cheat-sheet

Comment: so what's wrong with "select user from dual"?

Comment: it does not show me the current user.